# 9 V to 400 V DC-DC converter

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter, 555, geiger-muller-tube

I need to build a Geiger counter power supply circuit that will provide a 400 V DC output out of one of those 6LR61 9 V batteries. I thought about using a 555 timer to produce a square wave, feed it into a 1:45 transformer and then filter out the output, but I have no idea about what frequency and how many primary and secondary windings to use, and whether it would work at all.

**update:**

OK, thanks everyone for your effort but I guess I'll just go with a 555 inverter circuit like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XhtRF-ci0wQ/UEJ5fl6IgUI/AAAAAAAAAzM/0Ya3xvoZ8JM/s1600/555+timer+IC+based+12V+to+220V+Inverter+circuit+schematic+circuit+diagram.png) (sorry for the watermarks), with custom transformer and a filter on the output.

Comment: Try TI webench for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but webench didn't find anything. The ratio is probably too high.

Comment: How much current does the counter need? For very low current, a modest transformer step-up followed by a cascade might be suitable. For higher power a flyback is a good choice. With a 6LR61 you're not going to be able to get much power anyway.

Comment: The tube won't need much current, but the thing is that I don't posses the needed knowledge to calculate all the numbers, and I didn't find any close example of the power supply.

Comment: @Thatguy good literature available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier

Comment: There is no upper limit of turns ratio. You can use powerelab’s poweresim and “wind” your own transformer there. Or just use webench as a starting point for some lower output voltage with COTS magnetics, copy the primary and increase the turns ratio in your final circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a reputable one that runs from 5 volts and uses an inductor to get initial voltage magnification then a cockcroft-walton multiplier: -

[image]

[Maxim article that gives more detail](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3757). Use a voltage regulator to drop the 9 volts to 5 volts and because you are using a battery I'd urge you to use a buck regulator to prolong battery life.

There is also this that runs from a 555 timer and uses an LT700 audio transformer: -

[image]

[Full details here](http://www.creative-science.org.uk/geiger.html). But google really is your friend on this and you can find many images of circutis on-line.

Comment: Can I ask a question ? Why they use 1N4148, its max reverse voltage is only 100 V ?

Comment: @LongPham Each diode (in the C_W multipler) only sees a fraction of the overall output voltage.